# What method to programmatically add subview to NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I'm adding a `UIButton` to my `UIView` nib in the `drawRect` right now.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     self.button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
     [self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [self.button setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
     [self addSubview:self.button];
}
```

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325768/when-is-uiview-drawrect-method-invoked), it says `drawRect` is called whenever the views frame is modified. What method should I add my custom UI elements or should I create my own method and just call that.

Comment: override `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder`.  Call a method to add your button in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually i do it like this

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self load] ;
    }
    return self ;
}

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame] ;
    if(self)
    {
       [self load] ;
    }
    return self ;
}
-(void)load{
    //add your subviews here .
}
```